# Get fields of other content type by view relationship?

Tags: 8, nodes, views

I have two content type called `'Department'` and `'Student'`. I have created a view of content type `'Student'`, where  i want to fetch fields of `Department`.I followed below steps:

```
1.Created one reference field content of type 'Department' in Student content type.
2.Added relationship in the view for that field
3.Added field in the view table fields.
But output is not fetching the field value of other content type.
```

Reffered link: https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004

Comment: Double check that the relationship you added is referenc**ed** entity and not referenc**ing** entity.

Comment: when i click on add relationship, i saw only 'Content referenced from field_dept_ref' option. where 'field_dept_ref' is field in Student referring to department content.

Comment: try switching it to `Content Referecing from field_dept_ref`

Comment: "Content Referecing from" option is not there. Do i need to remove filter,where i mentioned content type='student'?

Comment: Add your Deparment to the filter. so type Derpartment, student